# Incorporating JavaScript into HTML to create a pantone-style column

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a pantone-style column, with one totally red div and the others all decreasing shades of that red. Basically, I've got a variable 'op' for opacity, that starts at 1 and decreases until it's equal to .1. Here's the code that I use (on Codepen). '.column' is my big container, and '.box' is for all the smaller divs. My issue is that the editor doesn't recognize 'op' as part of the div's style. How can I fix this?

```
var op = 1;
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
$('.column').append('<div class="box", style="opacity:op;">Hello.</div>')
op = op - .1
}
```

Comment: Break it out of the quotes `opacity:' + op + ';"` or else use an ES2015 template string.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's been a while and I totally forgot about that. It's working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var op = 1;
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
$('.column').append('<div class="box", style="opacity:'+op+';">Hello.</div>')
op = op - .1
}
```

Insert the variable

Javascript doesn't have a native string parser like most other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is a bit off here:
`'<div class="box", style="opacity:op;">Hello.</div>'`

should be written as...
`'<div class="box", style="opacity:' + op + '">Hello.</div>')`

```js
var op = 1;
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  $('.column').append('<div class="box", style="opacity:' + op + '">Hello.</div>');
  op = op - .1;
}
```

```css
.box {background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column"></div>
```